# is there a way to add margins or scaling in dompdf?

Tags: php, html, css, magento, dompdf

i have generated a pdf using dompdf and set the paper size as A6. now when i try to print the pdf in A4 and letter paper size, the left and top borders are getting cut. is there a way to generate the pdf so that it can be compatible with A4, A6, letter and legal paper sizes? it should start from the top right corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can define 1 size for a page in a PDF document as that is a media for print. (You can change the sizes on every page though if needed.)

However: if you create it either A6 and A4 and choose to print with 'scale to paper' (or 'fit to print area' or something similar) option than it should be the same but 2 times bigger. Actually that is the default in most of the PDF viewers to skip these issues.

Letter size has different aspect ratio, so you'll need remember to leave a bit bigger margins so both A4 and letter size can be printed out without missing parts :)